# Randomly get "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" while running robot framework test

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a test written in Robot Framework which runs over my application's Web-based User Interface. The problem is there are random times that the script can't access web elements and raise this error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8984)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmp4xd_ww/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8574)
    at WebElement.getElementAttribute (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmp4xd_ww/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11764)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmp4xd_ww/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12282)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmp4xd_ww/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12287)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmp4xd_ww/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12229)
```

I googled and I found out that it's related to my waits. Some times in my code, I wait for an element to be visible and then click on it:

```
wait until element is visible   xpath=//*[@id="UserTableForm:${defRow}:0"]/input   2
click element                   xpath=//*[@id="UserTableForm:${defRow}:0"]/input
```

I think some times the DOM actually changes the web elements between these two commands; but I don't know how to avoid that?

Comment: Is "2 seconds" the only argument you have tried so far? What happens when you try waiting it for longer, say "10 seconds"? One thing that is not related to your problem, it is better to use a variable to represent the same xpath if you are using it multiple times, for example, you could name a variable ${INPUT}    |    xpath=//*[@id="UserTableForm:${defRow}:0"]/input

Comment: I doubt the 2 seconds timeout will help here. AFAIK, it sets an explicit timeout for that keyword ONLY. If your element appears in 1 second, Robot won't wait another second. We face this problem aplenty in our framework as well. Though I'm not too sure what causes it, we see that it gets resolved if we add a Sleep of 2-3 seconds between the wait and the click. Does that help in any way?